# c++/boost analog of C# BlockingCollection?

Tags: c++, boost

I like `C#` thread-safe `BlockingCollection` that allows me to "block" until new items are available, using `Take` and `TryTake` methods, for example block maximum for 1 second: `orderActions.TryTake(out oa, 1000);`

What would be c++ / boost analog of `BlockingCollection`?

Comment: In Boost there's the opposite: lockfree thread-safe queue (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/lockfree.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [boost::lockfree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html) library to achieve desired behavior.
In that case you can implement `Take` and `TryTake` on top of pop method.

Or you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805041/c-equivalent-to-javas-blockingqueue) to protect `std::deque` with `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable` (answer written in terms of C++11 but you could use [boost::thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread.html) to access thread related stuff from older compilers).

**UPDATE**

Actually I don't recommend first way cause it kills whole idea of lock-free container :)
So, for the second case `TryTake (tryPop)` can be implemented with following code (just example)

```
template<typename PeriodT>
bool tryPop (T & v, PeriodT dur) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->d_mutex);
    if (!this->d_condition.wait_for(lock, dur, [=]{ return !this->d_queue.empty(); })) {
        return false;
    }
    v = std::move (this->d_queue.back());
    this->d_queue.pop_back();
    return true;
}
```

`PeriodT` can be `std::chrono::milliseconds`, for example. Quick sample:

```
queue<int> p;
int v;
p.tryPop (v, std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
```

Comment: I don't know how to implement Take and TryTake exactly. likely i should use `wait handle` but i was thinking to find something ready to use, cause it's too hard to implement for me :)

Comment: @javapowered: Threading unfortunately is hard. You really have to learn to build it from the primitives (and than you should use something already existing to avoid bugs, but you have to understand how it works).

Comment: do you know what is better to place in `queue`? should I allocate object, place pointer, dequeue, delete object? or I should place references? or I should place objects itself?

Comment: It depends on your task. In general, I wouldn't recommend raw pointers or just references. Placing objects itself good for Moveable classes which provide fast and cheap transfers across calls. In other cases use std::unique_ptr and std::shared_ptr to achieve memory safety and consistency.

Comment: what if I need no timeout, should I just use `p.tryPop(v, std::chrono::milliseconds(0)))` ?

Comment: adding reference to review of this code http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/49820/thread-safe-queue also how many consumer and producers this implementation supports?