# why we should put `std::unique_lock` under a local scope?

Tags: c++, c++11

Based on [C++ Equivalent to Java's BlockingQueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805041/c-equivalent-to-javas-blockingqueue)

```
void push(T const& value) { // original version
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->d_mutex);
            d_queue.push_front(value);
        }
        this->d_condition.notify_one();
    }

void push(T const& value) { // my question
        //{ // comment out the scope
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->d_mutex);
            d_queue.push_front(value);
        //} // comment out the scope
        this->d_condition.notify_one();
    }
```

**Question:** why we should introduce a local scope `{}` to cover the `std::unique_lock` inside the `put` function? Is it because we should release the lock first before calling `notify_one` otherwise the lock is hold while we calling the `notify_one`?

```
T pop() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->d_mutex);
        this->d_condition.wait(lock, [=]{ return !this->d_queue.empty(); });
        T rc(std::move(this->d_queue.back()));
        this->d_queue.pop_back();
        return rc;
    }
```

**Question:** why we should use `[=]` inside the `pop` function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it because we should release the lock first before calling `notify_one()` otherwise the lock is hold while we calling the `notify_one()`?

Correct. It's possible that the other thread spins up and attempts to grab the queue's lock before the producer thread has released it. Which would cause it to wake up (because of the condition variable), and then go back to sleep (because of the lock).

> why we should use `[=]` inside the pop function?

We are accessing `this`. The lambda needs to access `d_queue` through some method, and they chose copying `this` by value.

Comment: Q2> why not copying `this` by reference?

Comment: @q0987: It's a pointer, either would be fine. I'd probably do it as a reference personally.

Comment: Or `[=this]` be precise.

Comment: @q0987 That would be a syntax error. If you want to explicitly capture only `this`, and not implicitly capture it via a capture default (`[=]` or `[&]`), then use `[this]`.

Comment: @Praetorian, you are absolutely right. I just found out that `this` is a special variable. `[this]` means to capture the this pointer of the enclosing class.

Comment: @q0987 `this` is a prvalue, capturing it by reference makes as much sense as capturing `false` or `243` by reference. You can only capture `this` by copy.