# Is it possible to get data from a thread while it is running? C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a thread running as part of a program that I need to keep running through the duration of my program. However, as I run the program, I want to be able to periodically show what data is being processed on the thread (without stopping it).

Conceptually, is that possible and/or good practice? From what I have been reading about threads, it seems like in order to access a thread, you have put it to sleep, see what you want, and then start it again. Is there a way to "mirror" that thread? Even if I can do that, is that good practice to access a thread directly, or do I need to dump the information to a data structure first and then read it?

Extra Information:
I am not sure if this makes a difference, but I created a thread using the [C++ CreateThread function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I was just reading in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331536/windows-threading-beginthread-vs-beginthreadex-vs-createthread-c) that there was a memory leak problem with that method. However, I thought that HOW I create the thread changes the level of the OS it is working on and might affect whether or not I was able to access the thread or not.

Thanks for any advice in advance!

Comment: Normal approach would be for the thread to send an event somewhere. Without knowing your context, if you are working on files in a directory the thread might post a message each time it starts a new file. The alternative is horrible - the thread has to stop doing "real work" so it can process your "request".

Comment: @John3136 Okay, that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: You should look at std::thread and not fiddle directly with the Win32 if you can avoid it.

Comment: @CyberSpock Is it just safer?

Comment: @JustBlossom it's just better. In all sorts of ways. Especially argument passing, though.

Comment: @JustBlossom it is above all a portable way to work with threads and simpler IMHO. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread

Comment: There are lots of solutions. `std::atomic<>` is another simple method. Atomic variables have a speed penalty but can be written and read safely across threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `sleep` is not an option.

Better solution is to use [condition variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) to organize a blocking queue like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805041/c-equivalent-to-javas-blockingqueue).

And `std::thread` would be a good choice for multi-threading.

So having all this, your main thread can push a message to the queue and your child thread (which is popping messages) will then use it.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a `mutex` to guard the variable before you read or write to it: Look at the following [C++ Concept: Mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Mutex)
Also the [Mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) class can be of value.

If it is just a counter or some basic type you can also consider looking at a [atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) type.

As others have suggested, try to use [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) if you have c++11.

For asynchronous notifications that can be used to send data from one thread to another thread look at the Qt library and their [Signals and Slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) mechanism.