# Put all database operations in a specific thread using Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have a console application where after a timeout signal, a 2D matrix (15*1200) should be parsed element-by element and inserted to a database. Since the operation is time-consuming, I perform the insertion in a new thread using `QConcurrent::run`.

However, due to timeout signals, several threads may start before one finished, so multiple accesses to the database may occur. 
As a solution, I was trying to buffer all database operations in a **specific** **thread**, in other words, assign a specific thread to the database class, but do not know how to do so.

Comment: You could use a blocking queue in your thread, so that database operations can be posted in the queue, and processed sequentially by your thread. See this, for example of an implmentation of a blocking queue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805041/c-equivalent-to-javas-blockingqueue

Comment: You may use a worker object with slots for all database operations. Read Qt documentation for details: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is a classical concurrent data analysis problem. Have you tried using [`std::mutex`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex)? Here's how you use it:

You create some variable `std::mutex` (mutex = mutual exclusion) that's accessible by all the relevant threads.

```
std::mutex myLock;
```

and then, let's say that the function that processes the data looks like this:

```
void processData(const Data& myData)
{
    ProcessedData d = parseData();
    insertToDatabase(d);
}
```

Now from what I understand, you're afraid that multiple threads will call `insertToDatabase(d)` simultaneously. Now to solve this issue, simply do the following:

```
void processData(const Data& myData)
{
    ProcessedData d = parseData();
    myLock.lock();
    insertToDatabase(d);
    myLock.unlock();
}
```

Now with this, if another thread tries to access the same function, it will block until another all other threads are finished. So threads are *mutually excluded* from accessing the call together.

**More about this:**

Caveats:

1. This mutex object **must** be the same one that all the threads see, otherwise this is useless. So either make it global (bad idea, but will work), or put it in a the class that will do the calls.
2. Mutex objects *are non-copyable*. So if you include them in a class, you should either make the mutex object a pointer, or you should reimplement the copy constructor of that class to prevent copying that mutex, or make your class noncopyable using `delete`:

   ```
   class MyClass
   {
       //... stuff
       MyClass(const MyClass& src) = delete;
       //... other stuff
   };
   ```
3. There are way more fancier ways to use `std::mutex`, including [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) and [`std::unique_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock), which take ownership of the mutex and do the lock for you. This are good to use if you know that the call `insertToDatabase(d);` could throw an exception. In that case, using only the code I wrote will not unlock the mutex, and the program will reach a *deadlock*.

In the example I provided, here's how you use `lock_guard`:

```
void processData(const Data& myData)
{
    ProcessedData d = parseData();
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(myLock);
    insertToDatabase(d);
    //it will unlock automatically at the end of this function, when the object "guard" is destroyed
}
```

4. Be aware that calling `lock()` twice by the same thread has **undefined behavior**.
5. Everything I did above is C++11.
6. If you're going to deal with multiple threads, I recommend that you start reading about data management with multiple threads. [This](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01CY1VZM4) is a good book.
7. If you insist on using Qt stuff, here's the same thing from Qt... [QMutex](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutex.html).

Comment: Your answer is great, but the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-modules.html#threads-and-the-sql-module) states that *A connection can only be used from within the thread that created it*. Not sure if using locks around your database calls can save you from trouble. But I would say that using locks around **your calls** can't stop Qt itself from changing some structures in `QSqlDatabase` if for example a [notification](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldriver.html#notification-1) occurs while you are in the middle of your `insertToDatabase` functon.

Comment: @Mike While I see what you mean but not fully understand it, I can't suggest a better answer based on the question. There's very limited information. So I suggest the question has to be updated to contain more details, or the program at hand has to be modified to be thread-safe. Sometimes thread-safety requires changing the whole philosophy and plan of a program. I wish that the asker reads your comment, to be aware of how complicated thread-safety is, and make a decision.